# How to check if a crontab job works when it should

Tags: cron

So I've made a basic .sh file to clear my cache using the

```
sync; echo < 3 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

command. Then I saved it to my username in

```
/home/marc
```

Then I came across the crontab so I decided to use this sh file with crontab to run every hour as I noticed that my RAM is eaten up extremely quickly on my laptop. using crontab -e, I edited the file to this:

```
0 * * * * /root/clearcache.sh
```

My question is, have I done everything right? Have I editied the crontab file correctly and if so, how can I check that this job runs as it should do?

Comment: That's not how memory allocation works on Linux, if you flush your filesystem cache every hour, you're going to have a bad time. Read http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ before proceeding :-)

Comment: So are you suggesting that I get rid of this cron job? I've just quickly skimmed through this and I'm definitely a victim of thinking my RAM is being eaten haha!

Comment: Your crontab works. What your cronjob is stupid unless you *want* to reduce performance based on a timer for some reason (public computer that you want to discourage people from using?), but you're set up to run it correctly.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176232 points to /var/log/cron if you have permission to read it (typically root)

Comment: Yeah I've just read into the risks of constantly dropping the cache and decided to deleted the cron job. It was just bugging me as to why so much RAM was being eaten up haha but honestly, you guys have been really helpful! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer to check if a cronjob works when you expect it to (short of **reading the man page**) would be to add a simple cronjob that will report the date to a particular file:

```
0 * * * * date >> /tmp/cronjob.test
```

Then check it the next day (or whenever) and ensure it's triggering when you expected it to.

I personally would recommend reading the man page instead—it's faster—but the above is the longer lazier way.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like cron doesn't have any logging or debug option.

To check that your short script is run as expected, you could watch `strace -f -p $(pgrep cron)` in a terminal window.  Run `strace -f my-basic.sh` in advance so you know what it *should* look like.

If a cron script generates any output, it should be mailed to your user.  When you open a terminal it will tell you you have mail, and the `mail` command will show it to you... I'm afraid that command may be another "learning opportunity" :).

You can expect that any errors will cause your script to generate output, and hence mail.  That's the unix convention.  "No news is good news".

Comment: I've just ran the `strace -f` command and I got this: